# Execute a procedure when loading a WorkWith Smart Device in Genexus Ev3

Tags: android, genexus, genexus-sd

I'm working in a Genexus Smart Device app for Android. I need to display a message on the screen and this message is a result from a procedure. I'm working with a WorkWith Smart Device and the procedure returns the message in a variable that is displayed in the layout. I have called the procedure from the ClientStart, Load, Refresh and Start events for the pattern but the message is not displayed when the form loads. I tried the procedure whith a button and the message appears correctly. The procedure has one parameter and is an attribute received as parameter for the work with.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Could you add some example code to your question? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I'm developing a process auditing app, but some sections could not be evaluated and I'm displaying this sections with tab controls. Now the tabpage.visible is not working in Genexus Ev3 U2 so at least I want to show the user the sections that can be ignored. I created a procedure that returns a comma separated list with the sections to ignore; I have a variable for displaying this list in the WWSD for the transaction but I put the procedure call in all the start events for the WWSD like ClientStart, Load, Refresh and Start but the variable is displayed blank. Thanks